# Slickgrid Filtering without Dataview

Tags: slickgrid

Is it possible to filter a Slickgrid without using the DataView?

In case it isn't possible, how should the data array be structured in order to display correctly?

I don't have a working example atm. Thanks

Later edit:

After doing some more homework, a filterable datagrid is all about getting matching indexes in a nested array... to get a live sorted result-set that gets updated with grid.setData(filterData);grid render; one should do the following

```
function intersect(a, b) // find an intersection of 2 arrays (google result on SO
{
  var ai=0, bi=0;
  var a = a.sort();
  var b = b.sort();
  var result = new Array();

  while( ai < a.length && bi < b.length )
  {
     if      (a[ai] < b[bi] ){ ai++; }
     else if (a[ai] > b[bi] ){ bi++; }
     else /* they're equal */
     {
       result.push(a[ai]);
       ai++;
       bi++;
     }
  }

  return result;
}

// given results sets are arrays of indexes matching search criteria
a = [1,2,3,4];
b = [2,3,4,5];
c = [3,4,5,6];
d = [4,5,6,7];

// should reunite in a nested array
array = [a,b,c,d];

// check intersections for each array[k] and array[k+1]
k = array[0];
for (var i = 0; i<array.length-1; i++){
    k = intersect(k,array[i+1]);
}

console.log(k) // returns 4

// k array is the index array that
// is used to build filterData[i] = data[j]
// depends if id is stored in data or in case
// of a database, it is stored in data

// tested in firebug
// thanks
```

Comment: Your code is confusing since the original question (or filtering SlickGrid data) has nothing to do with how the data is structured and what the filters are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the underlying data array and call `grid.setData(filteredData)`.

Comment: will try, expect a reply in case I get stuck again, will make some tests and confirm your solution

Comment: to better understand the code I need to write, I need to trigger a function on table headers that greps the multidimensional data array and then grid.setData(filteredArray) ? am I on the right track or is there an easier approach?