# SlickGrid RemoteModel vs. Dataview Model

Tags: sorting, filtering, dataview, slickgrid

We're currently using the slick.remotemodel.js model implementation of SlickGrid for its remote Ajax loading functionality. With this example the only filtering provided is a simple Search element. What we're looking to accomplish is a much more robust filtering method of each column, such as what is used in this example: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html

Is there a way to easily combine the features of the Dataview model with the RemoteModel? Is it merely a matter of combining the functions of Dataview into the RemoteModel code, or is there more of a fundamental overlap in the functionality of each?

I was able to find the following discussion - which seems to be more of a workaround rather than an integrated solution: [Slickgrid Filtering without Dataview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189403/slickgrid-filtering-without-dataview)

Maybe I am just over thinking this, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

DataView does all of its sorting/grouping/filtering/etc. on the client since it has access to all of the data.  If you're doing it on the server, you'll have to implement all that in your server-side data provider.  There's no prescribed way of doing this since everybody's backend and needs are different.

Comment: It would be ideal to generalize this so that all the features could work out of the box regardless of whether the data is all on the client or retrieved as needed by the server.  Yes all backend's are different, but all that is required is a common contract/interface to adhere to.